# Error in table definition syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, syntax-error

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc text)' at line 6

My query looks like this...

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    title varchar(100),
    img varchar(100),
    price int,
    type varchar(10),
    desc text);
```

I'm sure it's something stupid that I'm overlooking this late at night but for the life of me I can't figure out why it won't go through. I'm still new to all of this but is there someway that the names for my columns are conflicting with names for data-types or SQL functions?

Comment: Preserve the sanity of yourself and others. Do not use reserved words in table/column definitions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DESC` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html). If you're going to use it as a column identifier you must wrap it in ticks

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  title varchar(100),
  img varchar(100),
  price int,
  type varchar(10),
  `desc` text
);
```

Comment: Thank you for that link, I thought there were reserved words but I couldn't find them for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

desc is a keyword. escape it with backquotes or use a different field name.